# Email not received with mail command from terminal in CentOS

Tags: centos, email, command, postfix

I am trying to send mail with the following command:

```
echo "Hello" | mail -s "Hello" myaddr@mydomain.com
```

and than checking the exit status as:
    echo $?

which outputs 0

Of course myaddr and mydomain was replaced with the original ones.

But I do not receive email.

I restarted the postfix service as:

```
service postfix restart
```

and it restarted successfully.

I found the error below in `maillog` :

```
May 13 05:36:13 vagrant-centos64 postfix/error[22703]: 4F82F62D2B: to=, relay=none, delay=21422, delays=21422/0.13/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=dena-travel.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
```

Comment: You might get more useful output by using the `-v` option to `mail`.

Comment: Did you look at the postfix logs?

Comment: I checked the maillog and found below:

May 13 05:29:17 vagrant-centos64 postfix/pickup[22233]: C8E2362EA9: uid=0 from=<root>
May 13 05:29:17 vagrant-centos64 postfix/cleanup[22512]: C8E2362EA9: message-id=<20160513052917.C8E2362EA9@vagrant-centos64.vagrantup.com>
May 13 05:29:17 vagrant-centos64 postfix/qmgr[22234]: C8E2362EA9: from=<root@vagrant-centos64.vagrantup.com>, size=485, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Comment: First of all, don't end up extending discussion in comment box, [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/282920/edit) your question and mention necessary information. and please post full error message which you found as "host or domain not found".

Comment: This looks as if your system cannot resolve domains. What does `/etc/resolv.conf` look like? Are there any DNS servers in it?

Comment: are you missing the resolver configuration in postfix's chroot ?